# Fastreport right to left matrix

Tags: matrix, right-to-left, fastreport

How to make fastreport matrix layout right to left?
Now , I Have a report which contains a matrix and works very well for me except I want a right to left layout for my matrix? 
Has anyone had the same problem? I really need help for this issue.

Comment: please provide more details about the matrix and show us something.

Comment: this
1 2 3 4


then
4 3 2 1